# How to rig a skeleton so that it can be controlled with physics?

Tags: game-engine, rigging, physics, constraints

I'm trying to rig a lego minifigure skeleton. I followed the instructions in this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B9iL1hmJXrI and was able to get the armature working and even make a walkcycle. I would like to add physics to the skeleton but I'm not sure if my setup precludes this. My aim is to have keyframe animations take precedence in certain situations - like when its walking - and the physics engine take over in others - like if it gets hit by something at which point it should behave like a rag-doll.

specifically:

1) Because its a mechanical rig should I even use an armature or just use constraints?

2) If I do use an armature, should the minifigure be a single mesh or can I keep the arms, legs, torso as separate objects?

Comment: You can't upload your file directly, but you could use www.pasteall.org/blend to upload, copy the link and paste it to an edit in your original question.

Comment: This might give you some ideas ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HryXEpIz-cg